# jQuery .load() - measure the time

Tags: jquery, firebug, google-chrome-devtools, jquery-load

I'm using jquery `.load()` to load some external(but within same domain) resourses into the page.

As this action is not visible through `FireBug Network` / `Chrome Network console` - **how can I measure the time of loading?**

---

**EDIT:**

If running locally ( not localhost ) FireBug will not record this action.

Make sure you are testing this using WAMP / XAMPP (localhost) or on an on-line server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using difference in time:

```
var startDate = new Date();
var startMilliseconds = startDate.getTime();

$('mycontainerselector').load('myurl.html', function() {
    console.log(new Date().getTime() - startMilliseconds);
});
```

some corrections may be needed :)

Comment: Very clever! Is the result in ms?

Comment: According to [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp) yes _(getTime() returns the number of milliseconds since 01.01.1970)_, but I didn't checked it.

Comment: Funny story - I get two different results - 25ms using this `count and log` method and 30ms reported by FireBug / Netword.

Answer (score 2):

[`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) makes an AJAX call and it is visible in the firebug console, are you sure you are doing everything in the correct way?

Comment: Yes, everything works fine. It is not being recorded. I don't know why.

Comment: Maybe because I'm running locally?

Comment: Did you check the ticker "show XMLhttprequests" in the "Console" drop down in firebug?Otherwise it won't show in the console

Comment: yes, that is checked. Once running on `WAMP / localhost` I get record of this action. If on `c:/www/etc...` nothing is being recorded (except http requests - jQuery)

Comment: Funny story - I get two different results - 25ms using this `count and log` method and 30ms reported by FireBug / Netword.

Answer (score 1):

you can use console.time() and console.timeEnd()

```
console.time('loading ajax');
$('#stuff').load('url.html', function() {
   console.timeEnd('loading ajax');
});
```

it will print "loading ajax: 1247ms" in the console.

Answer (score 1):

another way of measuring this is the following:

```
var startDate = new Date();
var startMilliseconds = startDate.getTime();

$('#stuff').ajaxStop(function() {
    console.log(new Date().getTime() - startMilliseconds);
});
```